# unit testing a method called from another class

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I am new to Android unit testing and I am using Mockito to do it.

I want to test my method which has a method from another class. I want to stub that method so that it should not be called. I am using `doReturn().when()` so that original method is not called but it is calling the original method.

Here is my code:

```
doReturn(true).when(myclass1mock).methodofclass1();
boolean a = myclass1mock.methodofclass1(); //here it return true
class2spy.methodofclass2(anyvalue);
```

The method I am testing is:

```
public class2 {
    public void methodofclass2(Value) {
        boolean value = class1.methodofclass1(); //here I don't want to call this method
    }
}
```

The problem is method of `class1` is called everytime. I want something so that `class1.methodofclass1()` is not called.

I am injecting using:

```
@Mock
class1 myclass1mock;
@InjectMocks
class2 myclass2;
@Before
public void setUp() {
    myclass2 = new myclass2();
    class2spy = Mockito.spy(myclass2);
}
```

Comment: how do you inject class1mock into class2spy?

Comment: see my edited answer

Comment: @MaciejKowalski I have edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to test the behavior of Class2, then i think you mixed up the annotations. Also i would take advantage of `@Spy` annotations rather that configuring it by hand:

```
@Spy
class1 myclass1Spy;

@InjectMocks
class2 myclass2;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Also, do not try not to spy the class which is being under test (class2). Use the real implementation.

Comment: Actually I am little confused about the @spy and original object implementation because both perform the same operations but spy is only a copy

Comment: if you do not perform any configuration, the yes, it is basically the same as the real impl. Spy lets you mock some of the methods to return certain values. In your  case that is only appropriate for class1. Class2 which the test case is concerned about, does not need to be spied.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation